# Unable to open workbook with PERL script

Tags: excel, perl

I am using a PERL script to create a workbook on an existing excel file via OLE.
I want to add a new workbook with this instruction -

```
 $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Add();
```

and then carry out certain operations with it.
However, on executing this code, I am running into the conditions where $Book is always equal to zero, and excel is becoming unresponsive after that.
I am including the code snippet below :

```
use File::Spec;
use Win32::OLE;
use File::Basename;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::NLS qw(:LOCALE :DATE);
use constant false => 0;
use constant true  => 1;
use constant NULL  => 0;


my $Excel           = "";
my $Book            = 0;
my $Sheet_1         = "";
my $excelfile       = " ";

print "execl";
my $RC = false;
$Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=1; 
$Excel->{Visible} =1;

  $excelfile=E:\script\workbook.xlsx;
  $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Add();
  print "\n".$excelfile."\n";

  if ($Book==0)
    {print "close any open Excel file\n If problem persist close Excel application from task manager";
    #return $RC;
    $Excel->Close(); 
    }

   $Sheet_1 = $Book->Worksheets(1);
   $Sheet_1->Activate();       
   $Sheet_1->{Name} = "testing_sheet";
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Disclaimer : I am a total noob at this :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=153486

You could try some debugging with these:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3; # Die on Errors.

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=1; 
$Excel->{Visible} =1;

  my $excelfile=E:\script\workbook.xlsx;
  print "Creating new workbook\n";
  my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Add();
  print "Saving to excelfile: $excelfile\n";
  $Book->SaveAs($excelfile);


  if (! defined $Book){
    print "close any open Excel file\n If problem persist close Excel application from task manager";    
    $Excel->Close();
    return $RC; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the debugging code, it seems that there is some problem in saving the file. I am getting an Win32::OLE error code 0x80010105 : "The server threw an exception" in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "SaveAs" 
Do you have any idea why this happens?

I tried the same code on a few different systems. it seems to be working on some machines, but not on the others.

Comment: So the code is working but you have problems in some machines. Did you tried to use local directory (%TEMP%)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missing the quotation marks?

```
    $excelfile='E:\script\workbook.xlsx';
```

Comment: That was a typo while posting the question. In the code it is working fine.